# Call g returns a Null Exception?

Tags: java, applet, awt

```
public class delaunay extends Applet implements Runnable {
    public Graphics g;
    public void paint( Graphics g ) {
        displaytri(po[eee],arr[0].p1,arr[0].p2);
    }
    public void displaytri(Point v1, Point v2, Point v3) { 
    g.drawLine(v1.x,v1.y,v2.x,v2.y);
    g.drawLine(v2.x,v2.y,v3.x,v3.y);
    g.drawLine(v3.x,v3.y,v1.x,v1.y);        
}
}
```

`po[eee],arr[0].p1` and all other points works fine when i try `System.out.println()` with them. Every variable `v1` `v2` `v3` have there own values and I tried to print those values inside the function `displaytri`.

This eturns an error:

> > Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Terminology please. A method either *returns* a null pointer or *throws* a NullPointerException. You aren't 'calling g', you are *deferencing* it. Sort out your concepts and you will understand your problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NEVER maintain a reference to any `Graphics` object created by the system.

This could put you outside of the paint pipeline and lead to unexpected paint artifacts.

Instead, pass the reference of `g` to the methods you need....

```
public class delaunay extends Applet implements Runnable {

    public void paint( Graphics g ) {
        displaytri(g, po[eee],arr[0].p1,arr[0].p2);
    }
    public void displaytri(Graphics g, Point v1, Point v2, Point v3) { 
        g.drawLine(v1.x,v1.y,v2.x,v2.y);
        g.drawLine(v2.x,v2.y,v3.x,v3.y);
        g.drawLine(v3.x,v3.y,v1.x,v1.y);        
    }
}
```

Comment: i thought of it but didnt know how to use it anyways thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized your instance/class variable `g`.

Try initializing it with the `g` variable of the `paint` method to your class variable `g` like this :

```
public Graphics g;
public void paint( Graphics g ) {

   this.g = g;
   displaytri(po[eee],arr[0].p1,arr[0].p2);
}
```

Comment: You should NEVER maintain a reference to any `Graphics` object create by the system.  Doing so puts you out side of the graphics pipeline and can lead to erroneous paint artifacts.  In this case the OP should be passing the reference of `g` to the method

Comment: Yes I thought that too, but didn't knew more about it, well thanks for it